# Why do I get a null error using @Autowired in serviceBoleta?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am doing an electronic invoice system project in spring boot with the SOAP library, now when I issue the XML file of the electronic invoice, I get a hashcode of the XML file of the electronic invoice, I am trying to update hashcode in an existing record of the invoice. The invoice has its own classes like Repository, Service, Controller. Until then I have no problem, the problem is the LecturaXML class to inject into the invoice service class. I get an error, indicating NULL.

BoletaRepository

```
@Repository
public interface BoletaRepository extends SearchRepository<Boleta, Long> {

    public Long countById(Long id);

    @Query("SELECT MAX(numeroBoleta) FROM Boleta")
    public Integer obtenerUltimoNumeroSerieBoleta();

    @Query("SELECT c FROM Boleta c WHERE c.numeroBoleta LIKE %?1%")
    @Override
    public Page<Boleta> findAll(String keyword, Pageable pageable);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.enabled = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void updateBoletaEnabledStatus(Long id, boolean enabled);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.hashcodeticketBoleta = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void actualizarHashCodeBoleta(Long id, String hashcodeticketBoleta);

    @Query("UPDATE Boleta c SET c.pendienteticketBoleta = ?2 WHERE c.id = ?1")
    @Modifying
    public void actualizarEstadoBoleta(Long id, String pendienteticketBoleta);
}
```

BoletaService

```
@Service
@Configurable
public class BoletaService {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(BoletaService.class.getName());

    public static final int BOLETAS_PER_PAGE = 15;

    @Autowired
    private BoletaRepository boletaRepo;

    public Boleta saveBoleta(Boleta boleta) {
        return boletaRepo.save(boleta);
    }

    public void actualizarHashCodeBoleta(Long id, String hashcodeticketBoleta) {
        boletaRepo.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(id, hashcodeticketBoleta);
    }

    public void actualizarEstadoBoleta(Long id, String estadoBoleta) {
        boletaRepo.actualizarEstadoBoleta(id, estadoBoleta);
    }
    
    public Boleta get(Long id) throws BoletaNotFoundException {
        try {
            return boletaRepo.findById(id).get();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException ex) {
            throw new BoletaNotFoundException("NO ENCONTRAMOS BOLETA CON ESTE NUMERO " + id);
        }
    }
}
```

LecturaXML

```
@Component
public class LecturaXML {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(LecturaXML.class);

    @Autowired
    private BoletaService serviceBoleta;
    
    private String codehash;
    private String estado;

    public String getCodehash() {
        return codehash;
    }

    public void setCodehash(String codehash) {
        this.codehash = codehash;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getRespuestaSunat(String path) {
        String respuesta = null;
        String nota = null;

        try {
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - iniciamos Lectura del contenido del CDR " + path);
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList responsecode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode");
            for (int i = 0; i < responsecode.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = responsecode.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList nodesc = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesc.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = nodesc.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = respuesta + "|" + datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList note = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Note");
            for (int i = 0; i < note.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = note.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                nota = nota + datoContenido.getNodeValue() + "\\n";
            }

            String[] cdr = respuesta.split("\\|", 0);
            //=== Guardar el link
            if (cdr[0].equals("0")) {
                this.setEstado("A");
            }
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + Arrays.toString(cdr).trim());
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + nota);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR codigo: " + cdr[0]);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - resultado del CDR Nota: " + cdr[1]);

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXException - El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: IOException - Error al leer el archivo de respuesta : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunat - ERROR: DOMException : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    /**
     * Metodo para obtener Respuesta Sunat con ticket
     *
     * @param path
     * @return respuesta
     */
    public String getRespuestaSunatTicketfe(String path) {
        String respuesta = null;
        String nota = "";

        try {
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - iniciamos Lectura del contenido del CDR " + path);
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();
            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList responsecode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode");
            for (int i = 0; i < responsecode.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = responsecode.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList nodesc = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Description");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodesc.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = nodesc.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                respuesta = respuesta + "|" + datoContenido.getNodeValue();
            }
            NodeList note = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:Note");
            for (int i = 0; i < note.getLength(); i++) {
                Node empleado = note.item(i);
                Node datoContenido = empleado.getFirstChild();
                nota = nota + datoContenido.getNodeValue() + "\\n";
            }

            String[] cdr = respuesta.split("\\|", 0);
            //=== Guardar el link
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR Observacion: " + nota);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR codigo: " + cdr[0]);
            log.info("LecturaXML.getRespuestaTicketSunatTicket - resultado del CDR Nota: " + cdr[1]);
        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: org.xml.sax.SAXException - El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: IOException - Error al leer el archivo de respuesta : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML.getRespuestaSunatTicket - ERROR: DOMException : " + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } finally {

        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    public void guardarHashYBarCodePDF417(String tipoDoc, String trans, String accion, String pathXMLFile) {

        try {
            String hashCode = obtenerDigestValue(pathXMLFile);
            /*============ALMACENANDO  BarcodePDF417(codigo de Barra)=========*/
            BarcodePDF417 barcode = new BarcodePDF417();
            String infobarcode = tipoDoc.equals("20") ? getInfoToBarCodeOD(pathXMLFile) : getInfoToBarCode(pathXMLFile);
            infobarcode = infobarcode.replaceAll("\n", "");
            log.info("==>infoBarcode:" + infobarcode);
            barcode.setCode(infobarcode);
            java.awt.Image img = barcode.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
            BufferedImage outImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            outImage.getGraphics().drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bytesOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(outImage, "png", bytesOut);
            bytesOut.flush();
            byte[] pngImageData = bytesOut.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngImageData);
            log.info("LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodePDF417 - resultado HashCode : " + hashCode);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("==>Error en generación de hash o barCode:" + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public void guardarHashYBarCodeQR(String tipoDoc, String numeroDocu, String pathXMLFile, Boleta boleta) {
        try {
            String hashCode = obtenerDigestValue(pathXMLFile);
            this.codehash = hashCode;
            /*============ALMACENANDO  BarcodePDF417(codigo de Barra)=========*/
            //QRCodeWriter barcode = new QRCodeWriter();
            String infobarcode = tipoDoc.equals("20") ? getInfoToBarCodeOD(pathXMLFile) : getInfoToBarCode(pathXMLFile);
            infobarcode = infobarcode.replaceAll("\n", "");
            log.info("==>infoBarcode:" + infobarcode);
            QRCodeWriter qrCodeWriter = new QRCodeWriter();
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(infobarcode, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 350, 350);

            Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(pathXMLFile.replace("xml", "png"));
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToPath(bitMatrix, "PNG", path);

            ByteArrayOutputStream pngOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream);
            byte[] pngImageData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray();
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngImageData);
            log.info("LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodeQR - resultado HashCode : " + hashCode);
            log.info("LecturaXML Guardando HashCode en la Boleta : " + this.codehash);
            System.out.println("Estado de la Boleta : " + this.getEstado());
            serviceBoleta.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(boleta.getId(), this.codehash);
        } catch (WriterException | IOException ex) {
            log.error("==>Error en generación de hash o barCode:" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public String obtenerDigestValue(String path) {
        String firma = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();
            //Obtener la lista de nodos que tienen etiqueta "ds:Reference"
            NodeList listaEmpleados = raiz.getElementsByTagName("ds:Reference");
            //Recorrer la lista de empleados
            for (int i = 0; i < listaEmpleados.getLength(); i++) {
                //Obtener de la lista un empleado tras otro
                Node empleado = listaEmpleados.item(i);
                //Obtener la lista de los datos que contiene ese ds:Reference
                NodeList datosEmpleado = empleado.getChildNodes();
                //Recorrer la lista de los datos que contiene el ds:Reference
                for (int j = 0; j < datosEmpleado.getLength(); j++) {
                    //Obtener de la lista de datos un dato tras otro
                    Node dato = datosEmpleado.item(j);
                    //Comprobar que el dato se trata de un nodo de tipo Element
                    if (dato.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                        //Mostrar el nombre del tipo de dato
                        if (dato.getNodeName() == "ds:DigestValue") {
                            //El valor está contenido en un hijo del nodo Element
                            Node datoContenido = dato.getFirstChild();
                            //Mostrar el valor contenido en el nodo que debe ser de tipo Text
                            if (datoContenido != null && datoContenido.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                                //System.out.println(datoContenido.getNodeValue());
                                if (datoContenido.getNodeValue() != null) {
                                    firma = datoContenido.getNodeValue();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: Se ha producido un error al leer el fichero\n" + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            log.error("ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return firma;
    }

    public String getInfoToBarCode(String path) {
        String respuesta = "";
        try {
            String IssueDate = "";
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //=====RUC
            NodeList nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:PartyIdentification");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            //=====InvoiceTypeCode
            NodeList InvoiceTypeCode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode") : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode");
            respuesta += InvoiceTypeCode.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====cbc:ID
            nodlist = raiz.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent().replaceAll("-", "|") + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:IssueDate")) {
                    IssueDate = nod.getTextContent();
                }
            }
            //=====>LegalMonetaryTotal

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:LegalMonetaryTotal").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:RequestedMonetaryTotal").item(0).getChildNodes() : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:LegalMonetaryTotal").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount")) { //NO EN : ND
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:PayableAmount")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }
            //=====>IssueDate
            respuesta += IssueDate + "|";
            log.info(respuesta);

            //=====>AccountingCustomerParty
            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:AccountingCustomerParty").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:AdditionalAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:org.xml.sax.SAXException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error IOException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error ParserConfigurationException - ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        } catch (DOMException exg) {
            respuesta = "LecturaXML:Error DOMException - ERROR: Al leer el archivo de respuesta" + path + "en getInfoToBarCode" + exg.getMessage();
            log.error(respuesta);
        }
        return respuesta;
    }

    public String getInfoToBarCodeOD(String path) {
        String respuesta = "";
        try {
            String IssueDate = "";
            DocumentBuilderFactory fabricaCreadorDocumento = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder creadorDocumento = fabricaCreadorDocumento.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document documento = creadorDocumento.parse(path);
            //Obtener el elemento raíz del documento
            Element raiz = documento.getDocumentElement();

            //=====RUC
            NodeList nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:PartyIdentification");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            //=====InvoiceTypeCode
            //NodeList InvoiceTypeCode = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode").item(0) == null ? raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:ResponseCode") : raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:InvoiceTypeCode");
            respuesta += "20" + "|";//InvoiceTypeCode.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====cbc:ID
            nodlist = raiz.getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent().replaceAll("-", "|") + "|";
                }
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:IssueDate")) {
                    IssueDate = nod.getTextContent();
                }
            }
            //=====>LegalMonetaryTotal

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cbc:TotalInvoiceAmount");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";

            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("sac:SUNATTotalPaid");
            respuesta += nodlist.item(0).getTextContent() + "|";
            //=====>IssueDate
            respuesta += IssueDate + "|";

            //=====>AccountingCustomerParty
            nodlist = raiz.getElementsByTagName("cac:ReceiverParty").item(0).getChildNodes();
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cac:PartyIdentification")) {
                    NodeList noi = nod.getChildNodes();
                    for (int x = 0; x < noi.getLength(); x++) {
                        Node nodx = noi.item(x);
                        if (nodx.getNodeName().equals("cbc:ID")) {

                            respuesta += nodx.getAttributes().getNamedItem("schemeID").getTextContent() + "|";
                            respuesta += nodx.getTextContent() + "|";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nodlist.getLength(); i++) {
                Node nod = nodlist.item(i);
                if (nod.getNodeName().equals("cbc:CustomerAssignedAccountID")) {
                    respuesta += nod.getTextContent() + "|";
                }
            }

        } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: El formato XML del fichero no es correcto\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error al leer el archivo de respuesta\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: No se ha podido crear el generador de documentos XML\n" + ex.getMessage());
            respuesta = "Error al leer el archivo de respuesta";
        } catch (DOMException exg) {
            System.out.println("==>Error while reading file " + path + " on getInfoToBarCode(path)\n");
        }
        return respuesta;
    }
}
```

I get this error on Null

```
2023-09-10T16:32:12.240-05:00  INFO 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] p.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML   : LecturaXML.obtenerDigestValue BarCodeQR - resultado HashCode : MTIpa+f0o7DYKtZebc7jJOviqjc=
2023-09-10T16:32:12.240-05:00  INFO 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] p.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML   : LecturaXML Guardando HashCode en la Boleta : MTIpa+f0o7DYKtZebc7jJOviqjc=
Estado de la Boleta : null
2023-09-10T16:32:12.243-05:00 ERROR 36024 --- [nio-8081-exec-5] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/admin] threw exception [Request processing failed: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaService.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(java.lang.Long, String)" because "this.serviceBoleta" is null] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaService.actualizarHashCodeBoleta(java.lang.Long, String)" because "this.serviceBoleta" is null
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.util.LecturaXML.guardarHashYBarCodeQR(LecturaXML.java:231) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.cpews.BolElectronica.generarXMLZipiadoBoleta(BolElectronica.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at pe.com.carbonstar.admin.boleta.BoletaController.generarBoletaElectronica(BoletaController.java:620) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Add relevant code from `BolElectronica.java` and `BoletaController.java:620`. I suspect you're using a POJO LecturaXML  object as I already commented on your previous question.

Comment: Please share the package details of these classes as well as your `@ComponentScan` annotation configuration in addition to what @void void requested. Since you might be using the aforementioned annotation implicitly via `@SpringBootApplication` , please include the class with this annotation and its package name as well.

Comment: I'm going to try to upload it on Github. Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add more code.

Comment: It was added to a repository on github  https://github.com/croelanjr/erpcarbonstar.git

Answer (score 0):

This is the relevant snippet from your repository (BolElectronica.java):

```
        LecturaXML lectura = new LecturaXML();
        org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();
        String resultado = "";
        String unidadEnvio = Util.getPathZipFilesEnvio(items.getEmpr_nroruc(), items.getDocu_fecha());
        log.info("Ruta de Unidad de Envio : " + unidadEnvio);
        String pathXMLFile;

        try {
            log.info("generarXMLZipiadoBoleta - Extraemos datos para preparar XML ");
            log.info("generarXMLZipiadoBoleta - Ruta de directorios " + unidadEnvio);
            log.info("generarXMLZipiadoBoleta - Iniciamos cabecera ");

            if (items != null) {
                pathXMLFile = unidadEnvio + items.getEmpr_nroruc() + "-03-" + items.getDocu_numero() + ".xml";
                //======================crear XML =======================
                resultado = creaXml(items, detdocelec, leyendas, unidadEnvio);
                log.info(resultado);
                //======================guardar Hash Y Barcode QR =======================
                log.info("generarXMLZipiadoBoleta - Crear Hashcode y CodeBarQR");
                lectura.guardarHashYBarCodeQR(items.getDocu_tipodocumento(), items.getDocu_numero(), pathXMLFile, items.getDocu_boleta());
```

The `lectura` instance is not a bean managed by spring, so it does not have the dependencies injected. Either provide them with a constructor or in some other way, or use the `BolElectronica` instance from the spring context by injecting it somewhere appropriate.

To clarify: the `serviceBoleta` private field is null in your `lectura` instance because you created the `lectura` instance yourself, and this is probably not what you want to do as you already have a singleton instance in the spring context which has the `serviceBoleta` field injected using reflection because you are using the `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: Thank you @void-void, So, I make a little code to update in the class BolElectronica.java

Comment: I have tried to do it in the Class BolElectronica.java, and the same error also appears.